# Selected Country / State From Dynamic Dropdown List

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using this Country / State dynamic selection on my code :

http://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/adding-dropdown-country-state-list-dynamically-into-your-html-form-by-javascript/

and here's the demo page : 
http://bdhacker.sourceforge.net/javascript/countries/

but, unfortunately when I create setting / member profile page which I need to display selected country and state so user can see what they already chosen, I can't just put user's selected as 'value' on it.

here's what I see on page source even I have select a country and a state :

```
Select Country: <select onchange="print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);" id="country" name ="country"></select>

City/District/State: <select name ="state" id ="state"></select>
```

how to put value on that ? because I did like this :

```
Select Country:   
<select onchange="print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);" id="country" name ="country" value="Indonesia"></select>

City/District/State: <select name ="state" id ="state"></select>
```

and still I don't see there's a country selected. thanks!

Comment: Have you included the function and data in your page? `<script type="text/javascript" src ="countries-2.0-min.js"></script>` (you'll obviously need to update the path to the file)

Comment: I have. I can see my dropdown menu works exactly like demo page. but when I add : <select onChange="print_state(\'state\',this.selectedIndex);" id="country" name = "country"><option value="Indonesia" selected>Indonesia</option></select> I still can't see a country selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution http://jsfiddle.net/yDAmR/

```
print_country("country");
$('#country').val('Indonesia');
print_state('state',$('#country')[0].selectedIndex);
```

Comment: bro, I just notice that there's a minor bug on your code... Uruguay, USA and Uzbekistan are in a row. when I choose USA, I don't see USA's state correctly. in fact, when I choose Uruguay I can see USA's state correctly. it seems there's something wrong with array indexing or something...

Comment: but when I put 'Indonesia' as you described, I can see Indonesia's state correctly. I think there are some countries have no states between Indonesia and USA so the indexing becomes false.

Comment: wait a second... why I don't see that error on your jsfiddle... I think I have to use same version of this countries.js with yours

Comment: Note: There is a countries-3.1.zip available, (not version 2 like the jsfiddle is using

Comment: @JeffreyKastner answer was written more than 10 years ago, I think, it's Ok if we leave the original version of country list.

Comment: @br3t 3.1 was more than 12 years ago (like 11 months later than version 2) but the fact still remains that there is a countries-3.1.zip available (and this is just a note to anyone who wants to use this).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see the USA states for other countries is that the JavaScript is missing a reset of the state drop-down list. Just add "option_str.length=0;  // Clear list" in the JS file before you split list array.